# jQuery event firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a notification plugin http://pjdietz.com/jquery-plugins/freeow/

together with the chosen plugin http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. When a user selects more than 1 item in a list, this fires an event to display an alert or in this case, the freeow notification.

This works well up until I click the notification to close and when the notification displays again, there are 2 notifications instead of 1.

I think this is referred to as bubbling and would appreciate any help as I am fairly new to jQuery and need help to find a solution.

```
$(function () {
    $("#box_frtv").chosen({
        width: "250px",
        max_selected_options: 1
    });

    $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected", function () {
        $("#boxerror").freeow("error", "sample test message. Thank you.", {
            classes: ["gray", "error"],
            autoHide: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Both plugins are buggy, agrhh. http://jsbin.com/lafugazuyuse/1/edit This solution might work for you. Prevents retriggering 'chosen:maxselecte' event within 100ms. If you'd like to show the only box message then use Brandon's way.

Comment: Updated my link. I still do not get how does JSbin work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `maxselected` event of the [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is a bit unreliable. Seems to fire multiple times creating multiple [freeow](http://pjdietz.com/jquery-plugins/freeow/) instances of your error message.

Only thing I can think of is to check for the error's presence prior to showing it. Something like this might work.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymt2Lzxn/1/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<select id='box_frtv' multiple>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>

<div id="boxerror" class="freeow freeow-top-right"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#box_frtv").chosen({
        width: "250px",
        max_selected_options: 1
    });

    var $boxerror = $("#boxerror"); 
    $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected", function () {
        //Check to see if the error is already showing. 
        //Might need a more specific class if you have multiple error types. 
        if($boxerror.find('.gray.error').length === 0){
            $boxerror.freeow("error", "sample test message. Thank you.", {
                classes: ["gray", "error"],
                autoHide: true
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Brandon. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any HTML or explained how you are loading the page, perhaps you are loading the page via Ajax or somehow calling the event registering twice??

In any way, you can try using `unbind()` before calling the `bind` method, which will make sure you are only listening once to the event.

Add this line before the `bind`:

```
$("#box_frtv").unbind("chosen:maxselected");
```

Your code should look like:

```
$(function () {
    $("#box_frtv").chosen({
        width: "250px",
        max_selected_options: 1
    });

    $("#box_frtv").unbind("chosen:maxselected");
    $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected", function () {
        $("#boxerror").freeow("error", "sample test message. Thank you.", {
            classes: ["gray", "error"],
            autoHide: true
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!